# rust install causing permission issue in terminal

Tags: rust

I installing rustc in Linux for school by using the command as explained in the wiki at https://www.rust-lang.org/

> curl --proto '=https' --tlsv1.2 -sSf https://sh.rustup.rs | sh`

The installation got completed and I added `. "$HOME/.cargo/env"` in my zshrc file. and when i open new tab I am getting permission error like this `zsh: permission denied: /Users/cerys/.cargo/env`. how to fix this

Comment: Please search before asking a question. Or several ones. This is not a rust problem but a general linux usage question.

Comment: Ok sorry I am new to stack flow. Will ask properly next time.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Check if the file `$HOME/.cargo/env` has executable permissions. If not then you can add it by doing `chmod +x $HOME/.cargo/env` and open a new tab or source it with `. $HOME/.zshrc`.